# Is the "mod" considered to be some kind of footnote or side note, or is it an operator?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

When the following is written:

```
a ≡ b (mod p)
```

can it be written as

```
a ≡ b mod p
```

or

```
a ≡ b modulo p
```

as well? (all 3 forms are ok?)

I also saw

```
x ≡ 7 ≡ y (mod 11)
```

in [this article](https://nrich.maths.org/5466), which started to make it confusing.

Is the `(mod p)` like a side note saying "hey, there is a world or universe in which we only consider the remainder after dividing by `p`, and in this world we say `a` is equal to `b` or `a` is congruent to `b` by the notation: `a ≡ b` or `a = b`", or is the `mod` some sort of operator like `+`, `-`, or in computer programming, the `%` operator so that `5 % 2 = 1` or `12 % 5 = 2`?

P.S. Later on, I found that you can even say, 3 is ***equivalent*** to 1, modulo 2, for 3 ≡ 1 (mod 2). The term "equivalent" is used. (This is in Cormen's MIT Algorithms book, 3rd Edition, page 54). So I suppose 3 is equivalent to 1, in the world of modulo 2.

Comment: You could also write $a\equiv b \pmod p$ as $a \equiv_p b$, where this means $a-b$ is divisible by $p$. $\equiv_p$ is a binary relation (in fact, an equivalence relation), not a "side note" or an operator. Also note that when we write $a\equiv b \pmod p$, we are *not* saying "$b$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $p$." We are saying "$a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $p$."

Comment: In the contexts you see above, mod does *not* work like the % operator from compsci contexts.  For example, note that $12\equiv 17\pmod{5}$ and that $17\equiv 2\pmod{5}$ however $12\neq 17\% 5 = 2$.  The definition is $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ iff $n\mid (a-b)$.  In practice, I would say that the mod is written in effect like a side-note to specify which $\equiv$ we are working with.  This allows us to write long chains such as $5^n-1\equiv 1^n-1\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ without having to use $\equiv_4$ in every instance which muddies the notation a bit.

Answer (score 4):

$a\equiv b\pmod p$ means "group all integers into equivalence classes depending on their remainder after division by $p$. Both $a$ and $b$ belong to the same equivalence class."

So you are right that the "mod $p$" in parentheses is a comment about the notation $\equiv$, and *not* an operator being applied to $b$. Incidentally I do recommend writing the parentheses, as
$$a\equiv b \bmod p$$
has the potential of being confused with
$$a=b\bmod p$$
which most people would interpret as meaning, "divide $b$ by $p$ and take the remainder. This remainder and $a$ are equal, as ordinary integers."

Comment: I heard that for `a ≡ b (mod p)`, some people also write it as `a = b (mod p)`... is it so?

Comment: Yes I've seen that too.

Comment: Just a note that the confusion arises because in computing, there is also the mod operator: `a % p` is an expression representing the operation of dividing a by p and returning the remainder. The connection is to realize that in the (mod p) world, the canonical set of representatives for the equivalence classes are the integers 0, 1, ..., p-1. So, you can think of the expression  `a % p` as saying: give me the canonical representative of a in the world (mod p).